# Admin bar nodes

Tags: php, javascript

I write a plugin. Inside it I use php and javascript files. I also use admin bar and I managed to display it with its nodes under the root menu.
I nedd the following functionality:
Clicking on one node should run some custopm php file on the server.
Clicking on another node should run a javascript file.
Is there a way to implement that?
Tnx
I.Sher

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. 
Add a custom link to the `href` attribute of the function, maybe with attributes for the url. This parameter plan you Parse, like about the global `$_GET` and run your file, script etc. if it the right parameters.

As example, see on the `href`-Parameter. I add the follow get-parameters in the href-Attribute.

```
    $scheme = ( is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http' );
    $url    = $scheme . '://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
    $str    = array( '?debug', '&debug', '#debugobjects' );
    $url    = esc_url( str_replace( $str, '', $url ) );
    $get    = '?';
    if ( FALSE !== strpos( $url, '?' ) ) {
        $get = '&';
    }
    $href = $url . $get . "debug#debugobjects";
```

The completly source to add my custom item in the Admin bar. You find all of this code in this [repo](https://github.com/bueltge/Debug-Objects/blob/master/inc/autoload/class-settings.php).

```
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(
            array(
                'parent'    => 'network-admin',
                'secondary' => FALSE,
                'id'        => 'network-' . self::get_textdomain(),
                'title'     => self::get_plugin_data( 'Name' ),
                'meta'      => array( 'class' => $classes ),
                'href'      => network_admin_url( 'settings.php?page=' . plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ),
            )
        );
        $scheme = ( is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http' );
        $url    = $scheme . '://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
        $str    = array( '?debug', '&debug', '#debugobjects' );
        $url    = esc_url( str_replace( $str, '', $url ) );
        $get    = '?';
        if ( FALSE !== strpos( $url, '?' ) ) {
            $get = '&';
        }
        $href = $url . $get . "debug#debugobjects";
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(
            array(
                'id'     => 'debug_objects',
                'parent' => 'top-secondary',
                'title'  => '<img style="float:left;height:28px;" src="'
                    . plugins_url( '/img/bug-32.png', parent::$plugin )
                    . '" alt="The Bug" />'
                    . __( ' Objects', self::get_textdomain() ),
                'meta'   => array( 'class' => $classes ),
                'href'   => $href
            )
        );
```